# Checking if an .exe is actually a .jar wrapped in an .exe

Tags: decompilation, java, jar, pe

Let's say I have a .jar file and wrap it into a .exe using any number of free utilities out there, like [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/).

Would it be possible to tell, given just the .exe, if it was generated using one such utility from a .jar file?

Comment: Your title says one thing and the question body another. Could you please clarify which one is the real question?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I did a quick test with JSmooth and it simply places the whole .jar file in a resource. You can easily see this by opening a JSmooth executable with [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) as the following screen shot shows (I used sun's deploy.jar from the java lib folder):

[image: Resource Hacker Screenshot displaying the jar as a resource]

For other utilities it might be different but you could use a tool like [binwalk](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2011/10/12/analysing-binaries-with-binwalk/) to look for the jar/zip signature inside the exe.

Comment: Good answer, though of course other tools might not use the same approach. The question was a bit vague anyway though, so I think answering that specific implementation is the right way to go.

Answer (score 8):

If the executable itself isn't packed or obfuscated you can often find the jar or class files by simply opening it in decompression utilty such as 7-zip.

[image: Minecraft launcher exe opened in 7-zip]

Comment: You can decompress a jar file using something like 7-zip, but the question was clarified to extracting a jar from an exe, not an exe from a jar.

Comment: I understood the question. You *can* open the exe in 7-zip to find jar/class files.

Answer (score 5):

The exe is probably just a small add-on that will execute the java interpreter on a set of packed classes. I don't know more details about how they go about their job, but there's big chance that the jar file sits unmodified inside the generated exe

You could take a look at the generated files with a hex viewer and there's a high chance you'll find a jar signature (to find out create a small jar file, look at it with a hex viewer, pack it and search for specific content from the original jar in the packed file)

Answer (score 5):

You can simply grep the file for "`javaw.exe`" or `java.exe`... This will usually be a pretty good indicator whether or not the program is a Java wrapper or not.

```
archenoth@Hathor ~/apps/Minecraft $ grep javaw.exe /host/Windows/notepad.exe 
archenoth@Hathor ~/apps/Minecraft $ grep javaw.exe ./Minecraft.exe 
Binary file ./Minecraft.exe matches
archenoth@Hathor ~/apps/Minecraft $
```

This is because wrappers usually contain the following:

[image]