# Decompiling or modifying .exe file generated from .jar

Tags: decompilation, jar, exe

I have one `.exe` file which is generated from `.jar` file but I'm not sure how it was made. I cannot open it with winrar or something. I need to modify it or just to decompile it. Any answer should be helpful.

Comment: how do you know it is generated from jar?

Comment: Possibly related: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/34/checking-if-an-exe-is-actually-a-jar-wrapped-in-an-exe/54#54